# Javascript separate string into different variables

Tags: javascript, string

I am looking to take a string and find all the spaces in it and separate that into different variables. I know I could use the `.split()` but that wouldn't make new variables. I would prefer to not use jQuery or other JavaScript library but if I have to, it wouldn't be the worst thing. Thanks!

---

Example, `John M Peters` would result in the variables `fname: John`, `mname: M` and `lname: 
Peters`.

Comment: Do all names always have a middle initial?

Comment: No they don't. I am doing a check before I split it to see if there is a middle initial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.split()` just returns an array, so you can easily assign new variables using that...

```
var str = "John M Peters";
var fname = str.split(" ")[0];
var mname = str.split(" ")[1];
var lname = str.split(" ")[2];
```

Comment: Ah, I so look forward to the future, when we will be able to do `let [fname, mname, lname] = str.split(" ");`

Comment: I think you can do something like this in coffee-script at least: `[fname, mname, lname] = "John M Peters".split(' ')`

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string like so:

```
var name = 'John M Peters';
var arr = name.split(' ');

var obj = {fname: arr[0]};
if(arr.length === 1) {
    obj.lname = arr[1];
} else {
    obj.mname = arr[1];
    obj.lname = arr[2];
}

console.log(obj.fname);
console.log(obj.mname); //could be undefined
console.log(obj.lname);
```

This solution will also work for a string that does not have a middle initial as well. You can see this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nDwmY/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how many spaces there are in the string, beforehand, you can do the following:

```
var str = "How are you doing today, my dear friend?";
numberspaces = str.split(" ").length; //you know how many spaces there are
words=str.split(" ");                 //it creates an array of words
var i;
for (i = 0; i < numberspaces; i++){
console.log(words[i]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function along these lines. This is just a quick-and-dirty and doesn't do any validation, I leave that up to you.

```
function parse_name(theName) {
    var nameSplit = theName.split(" ");

    var nameFields = {
            first  : nameSplit[0],
            middle : nameSplit[1],
            last   : nameSplit[2]
        };

    return nameFields;
}
```

Then you can call it any time you need to parse a name.

```
var parsedName = parse_name("John M Smith");

alert(parsedName.first); // Should alert "John"
alert(parsedName.middle); // Should alert "M"
alert(parsedName.last); // Should alert "Smith"
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers the others pointed out, I'd like to point out that Mozilla's JavaScript engine (spidermonkey) supports destructuring assignments:

```
<script language="javascript1.7">
  var s = 'John M. Peters';
  var fname, mname, lname;

  [fname, mname, lname] = s.split(/\s+/);
  alert('fname = ' + fname + ', mname = ' + mname + ', lname = ' + lname);
</script>
```

This is *not* portable, so not ideal for web programming.  However, if you're writing a plugin for firefox or thunderbird or etc, then there are a number of interesting language extensions available.

Comment: Correct, hence my caveat about portability ;p. But the OP did not specify the purpose of this JS code. For a plugin or such it's completely appropriate.