# How to separate multiple values in one variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have the following variable:

```
var myString='Description=TEST DESC&Stuff=things&Quantity=2';
```

How can I get the different items from this variable using split?
So there are multiple values, and the format is always the same:

variable=result and then followed by ampersand, then next variable=result.

I need to be able to assign each of those to actual variables

```
Description=TEST DESC;
Stuff=things;
Quantity=2;
```

Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406738/javascript-separate-string-into-different-variables

Comment: That looks like a query string, so the answers in the duplicate apply (the only difference is that you want to use `myString` instead of `location.search` or `location.href`

Comment: you would have to store these values in an object. you could use one of the solutions mentioned above

Comment: I wrote an answer there that would work as a drop-in if you delete the line `var url = location.search;` and take in an argument for `url` instead (appropriate renaming would be advised) http://stackoverflow.com/a/12197444/772035

Comment: There are a bazillion string parsing q&a on SO. I'll leave it to you to search one out and close this question.