# String to variables - javascript

Tags: javascript, discord

I am making a warn command of an bot (Discord Api)
I learnt how to split a string . So , The example is

```
var str = "warn @user reason";
var res = str.split(" ", 3);
```

and Its output will be

warn,@user,reason

and Its output will be "warn,@user,reason" 
I want to make the reply come in variables like

```
var commandname = "warn" ;
var username = "@user"; 
var reason = "reason";
```

because I want to store them in a file !
How can I remove the "," of reply and get the reply as the variables ?

Comment: You can set as `commandname = res[0]; username = res[1]; ...`

Comment: You already has the values in a variable called `res`, which is even easier to save into a file than separate variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript separate string into different variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406738/javascript-separate-string-into-different-variables)

Answer (score 5):

In your example, `res` will be an array of string objects. So you can access then by index:

```
var commandname = res[0];
var username = res[1]; 
var reason = res[2];
```

Comment: Should we really answer such basic questions?

Comment: Yep. As long as the question meets all the requirements (effort, clear, etc.) then it doesn't matter how 'simple' you or anyone else thinks it is. Only thing I didn't think of, maybe it's a duplicate already...

Comment: I agree with musefan, *simple* is relative

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify var declaration like , for further details about [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
var str = "warn @user reason";
var res = str.split(" ", 3);
var [commandname,username,reason ] = res;
console.log(commandname);
console.log(username);
console.log(reason);
```

**Note**: It depends upon ES version and do not support by IE

Comment: Depends on the ES version

Comment: Never knew that, it's good to learn... though I doubt I would use it anytime soon. Doesn't seem like much of a time saver for the risk of compatibility

Comment: Unless specified, it's about time we put ES5 were it belongs, (in the bin)..  If the OP specifically asks for ES5, fair enough.  But come on..!!  As a default javascript questions ES6 should be the norm..

Comment: @musefan It's called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: yes, added link for  Destructuring assignment  in answer and note as well